# How to prevent SQL injection with number data

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sql-injection

I write short source code and it works well. But I want to prevent SQL injection. Because this code cannot prevent SQL Injection.

This is my original code

```
router.get(`/sitemap/:page`, function(req, res, next) {
  let pageNumber = String(req.params.page) + "00";
  db.query(
    `SELECT * FROM user order by displayId*1 LIMIT ${pageNumber}, 100`,
    function(error, data) {
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      }
      // console.log(data);
      res.render("sitemap", {
        dataarray: data,
        pageNumber: pageNumber
      });
    }
  );
});
```

And it works well but cannot prevent SQL Injection, so I tried this method but it has error because of the ' character.

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, 100' at line 1
```

[Tried Another method]

```
router.get(`/sitemap/:page`, function(req, res, next) {
  let pageNumber = String(req.params.page) + "00";
  db.query(
    `SELECT * FROM user order by displayId*1 LIMIT ?, 100`,
    [pageNumber], // I FIX THIS PART!!!!
    function(error, data) {
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      }
      // console.log(data);
      res.render("sitemap", {
        dataarray: data,
        pageNumber: pageNumber
      });
    }
  );
});
```

How can I solve this problem. I think it should be string so I tried `String(pageNumber)` But still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenating params in string is always inviting SQL Injection. Why not putting `displayId` inside params array like you did for `pageNumber` ?

```
let pageNumber = String(req.params.page) + "00";
db.query(`SELECT * FROM user order by ? LIMIT ?, 100`,
                 [Number(displayId), pageNumber],
```

Also, you may use `Number` to parse string as number instead using multiply with 1.
It should solve your problem.

Comment: binds in parameterized queries cannot be used with ORDER BY

Answer (score -1):

Prefer to use values in variable, 
Avoid using inline query,
Try using stored procedure.